# Why won't it let me augment my soldiers into MEC Troopers in XCOM?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

So, I just got a few of my soldiers in Enemy Within up to Colonel Rank, and another soldier up to Captain so I decided I was going to make them into MEC Troopers to balance out with my Psionics. However, it won't let me. When I go to select them for the augmenting process their names are grayed out. But I can modify their genes if I want to, though I haven't yet on either of them.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They're not Psionics either*

Comment: do you have enough meld for the augmentation?

Comment: can you provide screenshot?

Answer (score 7):

You need the following to make a MEC Trooper:

- a Cybernetics Lab
- §10 and 10 Meld
- a soldier who is **not** genetically modified, **not** psionic, and **not** a rookie

If the soldiers in question are Colonel/Captain, not psionic, and have no genetic modifications, then it should work (assuming you have the cash and the meld).

Note that initially the soldier also needed to not be wounded, but this requirement was removed in a patch a couple years after launch and does not apply if you're up to date.

Comment: This may have been accurate in a previous version, but in current play being wounded does not prevent augmentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need the Cybernetics Lab, §10 and 10 Meld for a MEC Trooper. You don't need a MEC Suit to augment a soldier(but it is strongly recommeded). On the selection screen the third and last column shows the state of the soldier. There you can also read a reason for the inability to augment(for example "Can't Augment Rookies").

I have only seen two greyed out soldier types during my playthrough:

- Rookies
- MEC Troopers

Comment: Psionics would also be greyed out. But, the asker has said that the soldiers in question are not psionic and are of Captain or Colonel rank. *scratches head*

Comment: I wouldn't recommend building a MEC suit until after you have a MEC trooper to wear it. Suits build instantly, and as soon as you finish your first augmentation, you're sent to the suit-building screen (IIRC). It's more convenient and a bit safer to augment a trooper, then build the suit than to build the suit first.

Comment: A year after the fact - you can't build your first suit until you augment a soldier (at least on normal).